# Preserve 'variables' in a regex search and replace

Tags: vim

In Vim, I want to do a search and replace that includes:

```
[0-9]*
```

And in the replace part, I want whatever was in that vague range to be carried over and used.

For example let's say I have this:

```
getNumber(42).roundToTenth();
getNumber(43).roundToTenth();
getNumber(44).roundToTenth();
getNumber(45).roundToTenth();
getNumber(46).roundToTenth();
getNumber(47).roundToTenth();
```

and want to do a search and replace to change it to

```
DontGetNumber(42).roundDownTenth();
DontGetNumber(43).roundDownTenth();
DontGetNumber(44).roundDownTenth();
DontGetNumber(45).roundDownTenth();
DontGetNumber(46).roundDownTenth();
DontGetNumber(47).roundDownTenth();
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Would doing 2 simple substitutions meet your criteria? `:%s/get/DontGet/|%s/To/Down`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you mean `[0-9].*` (number followed by zero or more characters).  You can use capturing parentheses and use the backreference in the substitution.

```
s/[0-9]\(.*\)/\1/
```

The `\1` will be whatever was captured.  Change the replacement expression as needed.

```
s/getNumber(\([0-9]*\)).*/DontGetNumber(\1).roundDownTenth();
```

Comment: Thank you! But do you mind giving more of a.... Layman explanation. It looks like your answering what I need, but I can't say I fully understand or can implement.

Comment: @bzupnick give me an example input and output and I will write the expression for you.  `vim` is not really a layman's tool, though... You should look up things you don't understand like `backreference` and `subsitution` maybe

Comment: I know I've got a lot to learn ;) And I edited in a simplistic example

Answer (score 0):

You really want to use search/replace for this?

Personnally, I'd rather do something like :%g/Number/norm! ^~IDont^[fT2sDown^[

use a record with q[register] and fill the part after norm! with c-r [register]